# How to resize QWidget added in QGraphicScene through QGraphicsProxy?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsrectitem

I have added a widget to a graphic scene (QGraphicScene) through a QGraphicsProxyWidget. To move and select the widget added QGraphicsRectItem handle.
To resize widget added QSizegrip to widget. But when i resize widget more than the QGraphicsRect item rect right and bottom edges goes behind .How to overcome this problem?
**When i resize widget graphics rect item should resize or vice-versa should happen. how to do this?** Any other ideas are welcome.
Here is the code

```
     auto *dial= new QDial();                                        // The widget
     auto *handle = new QGraphicsRectItem(QRect(0, 0, 120, 120));    // Created to move and select on scene
     auto *proxy = new QGraphicsProxyWidget(handle);                 // Adding the widget through the proxy

     dial->setGeometry(0, 0, 100, 100);
     dial->move(10, 10);

     proxy->setWidget(dial);

     QSizeGrip * sizeGrip = new QSizeGrip(dial);
     QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(dial);
     layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
     layout->addWidget(sizeGrip, 0, Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignBottom);

     handle->setPen(QPen(Qt::transparent));
     handle->setBrush(Qt::gray);
     handle->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable | 
     QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);

     Scene->addItem(handle); // adding to scene
```

Here is the Output::
   Before Resize
[image: Before Resize]
After Resize
[image: After Resize]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Cause

The *QGraphicsRectItem*, which you use as a handle, is not aware of the size changes of *QDial*, so it does not respond by resizing itself.

## Limitation

*QWidget* and its subclases do not provide something like a `sizeChanged` signal out of the box.

## Solution

Considering the cause and the given limitation, my solution would be the following:

1. In a subcalss of *QDial*, say *Dial*, add a new signal `void sizeChanged();`
2. Reimplement the `resizeEvent` of *Dial* like this:

in dial.cpp

```
void Dial::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    QDial::resizeEvent(event);

    sizeChanged();
}
```

3. Change `auto *dial= new QDial();` to `auto *dial= new Dial();`
4. Add the following code after `Scene->addItem(handle); // adding to scene`:

in the place, where your example code is

```
connect(dial, &Dial::sizeChanged, [dial, handle](){
        handle->setRect(dial->geometry().adjusted(-10, -10, 10, 10));
    });
```

**Note:** This could be also solved using [eventFilter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) instead of subclassing *QDial*. However, from your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52006987/5366641) I know that you already subclass *QDial*, that is why I find the proposed solution more suitable for you.

## Result

This is the result of the proposed solution:

[image: before resize]

[image: after resize]

Comment: this dial i can enlarge upto some dimension after that i can't enlarge. If i put multiple objects resizing  that object behaves randomly either restrict width or height.please let me know why it's happening or solution

Comment: @Sagar, I do not quite understand what you mean.  Could you please post another question and describe this particular problem in detail.

Comment: here is link to question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060862/why-i-cant-enlarge-widget-added-to-qgraphicscene-by-qsizegrip