# Why I can't enlarge a widget added to QGraphicScene by QSizeGrip?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsrectitem

I have added a widget to a graphic scene *QGraphicScene* through a QGraphicsProxyWidget. To move it I have set *QGraphicsRectitem* as its parent. The widget is resized with the use of a sizegrip.

The first time I create an object I can enlarge it upto some dimension. The second time I can enlarge it less than the first one. The third time less than the second one and so on.

It seems to me that it behaves randomly. Why is this happening?

Here is the code:

```
void GraphicsView::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)// subclass of QGraphicsView
{

  if(event->mimeData()->text() == "Dial")
  {
   auto *dial= new Dial;      // The widget
   auto *handle = new QGraphicsRectItem(QRect(event->pos().x(),event->pos().y(), 120, 120));    // Created to move and select on scene
   auto *proxy = new QGraphicsProxyWidget(handle); // Adding the widget through the proxy
   dial->setGeometry(event->pos().x()+10,event->pos().y()+10, 100, 100);
   proxy->setWidget(dial);
   QSizeGrip * sizeGrip = new QSizeGrip(dial);
   QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(dial);
   layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
   layout->addWidget(sizeGrip, 0, Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignBottom);

   handle->setPen(QPen(Qt::transparent));
   handle->setBrush(Qt::gray);
   handle->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable |
   QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);

   scene->addItem(handle); // adding to scene 

   connect(dial, &Dial::sizeChanged, [dial, handle](){ handle->setRect(dial->geometry().adjusted(-10, -10, 10, 10));}); 
  }  }
```

[image: code]

I cannot enlarge the widget more than that, what is shown in the image.

Comment: Your code creates one Dial. Show, please, where and how you create the other dials. I already suspect what is the cause, but show it please, just to be sure.

Comment: @scopchanov Dynamically creating objects.. When a dial object dropped on scene it creates dial added to scene...void GraphicsScene::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)  from this event.

Comment: Great, but could you please show the exact code for the creation? It is important for what I guess is the problem.

Comment: @scopchanov i added verficable example link Please go throgh this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52069804/in-qgraphicscene-why-enlarging-widget-restricted-after-some-size?noredirect=1#comment91094055_52069804

Comment: @scopchanov I am creating objects dynamically when object item is dropped  on graphic scene...

Comment: I understand that, but unfortunatelly that does not give me the information I am looking for. I really want to help you with your problem, but in order to do that I need to see the exact code for that. Show please your drop event handler.

Comment: @scopchanov drop event added...In Drop event based on drop text creating objects . Graphics View is subclass of QGraphicsView... To resize,move and select widget in scene any other solutions are welcome...

Comment: @Sagar Why do you create 2 post with the same question? What do you expect to happen? Please delete the other post, it bothers to see 2 posts with the same content.

Comment: @Sagar, _second time i can enlarge less than first one_ is not true. Try to move the widget upwards and to the left and you will be able to resize it as much as the first one.

Comment: @scopchanov  yes you are correct but first one also prob.. can't enlarge more than that...it's restricted that size only.

Comment: @Sagar, in the constructor of _GraphicsView_, after `scene` is set as the scene of the view, add `setSceneRect(0, 0, 2000, 2000);` and you will probably see two scrollbars. Resize the widget, then move the scrollbars and you can resize it more.

Comment: @scopchanov real project pic link... Here i can move that object and resize but its restricated to some size ..https://drive.google.com/open?id=18KbT87QfmsQBanM0TgUKrhGKb_VsT_-n

Comment: @Sagar, what happens if you make the window bigger?

Comment: @scopchanov i setted scene rect to (2000,2000) but same problem i am getting.

Comment: @Sagar, please answer this: _what happens if you make the window bigger?_

Comment: @scopchanov sorry i am not getting which window...maximized window only is their

Comment: @Sagar, the application window. Do you have scrollbars when you make the scene 2000x2000?

Comment: @scopchanov  yes you are correct... scroll Bar moving i can resize....may be scene rect problem

Comment: @Sagar, try to adjust the position of the scrollbars when resizing the widget.

Comment: @scopchanov  scene rect problem...In running project  initially scene is small , i can enlarge upto some size, if i enlarge scene means again i can enlarge that object upto some more size...

Comment: @scopchanov Thanq for your patienance.. yes  i can resize after scrolling

Comment: @Sagar, you are welcome!

Comment: @scopchanov yes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *Dial* can't be resized past the GraphicView's right (horizonally) and bottom (vertically) edges. If you make the scene big enough, say 2000x2000 (`setSceneRect(2000, 2000);`), scrollbars will appear. If you move the scrollbars manually, you will be able to enlarge your widgets more.

You could also experiment with automatic scrollbar movement by changing the lambda function like this:

```
connect(dial, &Dial::sizeChanged, [this, dial, handle](){
    handle->setRect(dial->geometry().adjusted(-10, -10, 10, 10));

    int dx = handle->rect().bottomRight().x() > viewport()->rect().bottomRight().x();
    int dy = handle->rect().bottomRight().y() > viewport()->rect().bottomRight().y();

    if (dx > 0) {
        horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(horizontalScrollBar()->value() + dx);
    }

    if (dy > 0) {
        verticalScrollBar()->setValue(verticalScrollBar()->value() + dy);
    }
});
```

Please note, that although this code works, is is very cumbersome. However, it could give you an idea how to start.

Comment: @Sagar, I am sorry, I did not understand that.

Comment: actually now resizing dial object by sizegrip then setting rect of qgraphicsrect item, doing reverse,resize graphics rect item then set geometry of dial

Comment: @Sagar, I understand now. Hence my question: how are you going to resize the QGraphicsRectitem?

Comment: I got code this link https://github.com/cesarbs/sizegripitem/blob/master/SizeGripItem.cpp...  i  can resize qgraphicsrect .. but dial object i cant

Comment: @Sagar, it seems like a time for another question :)

Comment: @Sagar, please describe the problem in detail,.