# Why QGraphicsProxyWidget does not resize properly after dropping into QGraphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsproxywidget

I have a `QListWidget` and a `QGraphicsView` both subclassed to overwrite some of their members.
I prepared a minimal verifiable example showing the problem I have.

From the `QListWidget` I can drag and drop specific field represented by a `QTableWidget` and drop them into a `QGraphicsView` and in order to do that I am using a `QGraphicsProxyWidget` approach as shown below.

It is important to mention that the green `QGraphicsRectItem` it is used to move around the `QTableWidget` as well as adjusting its dimension.

**The problem:** dragging from the `QListWidget` is not a problem. But dropping into `QGraphicsView` is a problem because as you see the `QGraphicsRectItem` is right on top of the `QTableWidget`.

The minimal verifiable example can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/ERaggi/so_qproxy/src/master/) and below for completeness:

[image: proxy1]

**However** as soon as I touch the `QSizeGrip` bottom right of the `QGraphicsProxyWidget` the `QGraphicsRectItem` adjust itself with the dimension of the `QTableWidgetItem`:

[image: proxy2]

Below the minimal verifiable example:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsView>

#include "scene.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Scene *mScene;

};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mScene = new Scene;
    ui->graphicsView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(mScene);
    ui->graphicsView->show();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**optionlist.h**

```
#ifndef OPTIONLIST_H
#define OPTIONLIST_H


#include <QListWidget>

class OptionList : public QListWidget {
public:
  OptionList(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

protected:
  void startDrag(Qt::DropActions supportedActions);
};

#endif // OPTIONLIST_H
```

**optionlist.cpp**

```
#include "optionlist.h"

#include <QDrag>

OptionList::OptionList(QWidget *parent) : QListWidget(parent) {

  setDragEnabled(true);
  setDropIndicatorShown(true);
  setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
  setDefaultDropAction(Qt::CopyAction);
  setViewMode(QListView::ListMode);

  for (const QString &workspaceTree : {"Images", "Path", "Connection"}) {
    QListWidgetItem *img = new QListWidgetItem;
    img->setText(workspaceTree);
    img->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable |
                   Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled);
    addItem(img);
  }
}

void OptionList::startDrag(Qt::DropActions supportedActions) {
  if (supportedActions & Qt::CopyAction) {
    QList<QListWidgetItem *> m_items = selectedItems();
    if (m_items.isEmpty())
      return;
    QMimeData *data = mimeData(m_items);
    QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);
    QPixmap pixmap("/home/Icon_icon.png");
    drag->setPixmap(pixmap);
    drag->setMimeData(data);
    drag->setHotSpot(pixmap.rect().center());
    drag->exec(Qt::CopyAction);
  } else
    QListWidget::startDrag(supportedActions);
}
```

**customtablewidget.h**

```
#ifndef CUSTOMTABLEWIDGET_H
#define CUSTOMTABLEWIDGET_H

#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QResizeEvent>

class CustomTableWidget : public QTableWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CustomTableWidget(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QTableWidget(parent){}
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);

signals:
    void sizeChanged();

};

#endif // CUSTOMTABLEWIDGET_H
```

**customtablewidget.cpp**

```
#include "customtablewidget.h"

void CustomTableWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    QTableWidget::resizeEvent(event);

    emit sizeChanged();
}
```

And finally where the problem is:

**scene.h**

```
#ifndef SCENE_H
#define SCENE_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>

class Scene : public QGraphicsScene
{
public:
    Scene(QObject *parent = nullptr);

protected:
  void dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
  void dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
  void dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
};

#endif // SCENE_H
```

**scene.cpp**

```
#include "scene.h"
#include "customtablewidget.h"

#include <QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent>
#include <QMimeData>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QGraphicsProxyWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QMetaEnum>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QSizeGrip>

Scene::Scene(QObject *parent)
{
    setBackgroundBrush(Qt::lightGray);

}

void Scene::dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event) {
  if (event->mimeData()->hasFormat("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist"))
    event->setAccepted(true);
}

void Scene::dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event) {
  if (event->mimeData()->hasFormat("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist"))
    event->setAccepted(true);
}

void Scene::dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event) {
    QByteArray encoded =
      event->mimeData()->data("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist");
    QDataStream stream(&encoded, QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    QStringList rosTables;
    QString newString;

    while (!stream.atEnd()) {
    int row, col;
    QMap<int, QVariant> roleDataMap;
    stream >> row >> col >> roleDataMap;
    rosTables << roleDataMap[Qt::DisplayRole].toString();
    }
    for (const QString &tableType : rosTables) {
        if(tableType == "Images")
        {
            QPoint initPos(0,0);
            CustomTableWidget *wgt = new CustomTableWidget;
            QGraphicsRectItem *proxyControl = addRect(initPos.x(), initPos.y(), wgt->width(), 20, QPen(Qt::black), QBrush(Qt::darkGreen)); // widget->width() works properly here because of the resize(layout->sizeHint()) that we have used inside it
            QSizeGrip * sizeGrip = new QSizeGrip(wgt);
            QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(wgt);
            //QGraphicsRectItem *proxyControl = addRect(initPos.x(), initPos.y(), wgt->width(), 20, QPen(Qt::black), QBrush(Qt::darkGreen));

            layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            layout->addWidget(sizeGrip, 0, Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignBottom);

            connect(wgt, &CustomTableWidget::sizeChanged, [wgt, proxyControl](){
                proxyControl->setRect(wgt->geometry().adjusted(-10, -10, 10, 10));
            });

            proxyControl->setPos(initPos.x(), initPos.y());
            proxyControl->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
            proxyControl->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);

            wgt->setColumnCount(2);
            wgt->setRowCount(2);
            for (int ridx = 0 ; ridx < wgt->rowCount() ; ridx++ )
            {
                for (int cidx = 0 ; cidx < wgt->columnCount() ; cidx++)
                {
                    QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem();
                    item->setText(QString("%1").arg(ridx));
                    wgt->setItem(ridx,cidx,item);
                }
            }
            QGraphicsProxyWidget * const proxy = addWidget(wgt);
            // In my case the rectangular graphics item is supposed to be above my widget so the position of the widget is shifted along the Y axis based on the height of the rectangle of that graphics item
            proxy->setPos(initPos.x(), initPos.y()+proxyControl->rect().height());
            proxy->setParentItem(proxyControl);
        }
    }
}
```

I did extensive research about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060862/why-i-cant-enlarge-a-widget-added-to-qgraphicscene-by-qsizegrip) topic and came across [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52024492/how-to-resize-qwidget-added-in-qgraphicscene-through-qgraphicsproxy) which was very useful because made me solve the resizing issue inside the `QGraphicsView` but it didn't make me solve the drop problem of the widget inside the `QGraphicsView`.

The post I mentioned proceed to subclass the widget desired and add an additional signals called `sizeChanged();` and that is what I did.

I additionally moved the following statement after AND before the `QSizeGrip` declaration:

```
        connect(wgt, &CustomTableWidget::sizeChanged, [wgt, proxyControl](){
            proxyControl->setRect(wgt->geometry().adjusted(-10, -10, 10, 10));
        });
```

But it didn't cause any change and I still have the bug.

Thanks for pointing in the right direction for solving this problem.

Comment: Please tag your questions as qt as well.

Comment: Hello @scopchanov and thanks for stopping by and reading the question. Ok I added qt in the tag! :)

Comment: :) Great. Now I won't miss your questions. Now give me 1 min to write a solution.

Answer (score 0):

### Cause

You create `proxyControl` giving `wgt->width()` as a width:

```
QGraphicsRectItem *proxyControl = addRect(initPos.x(), initPos.y(), wgt->width(), 20, QPen(Qt::black), QBrush(Qt::darkGreen));
```

However, at that time `wgt` does not have its final geometry.

### Solution

Setup `proxyControl` **after** you are done with `wgt`.

### Example

Here is an example I have written for you to demonstrate how the proposed solution could be implemented. Change your `dropEvent` like this:

```
void Scene::dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
    QByteArray encoded =
            event->mimeData()->data("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist");
    QDataStream stream(&encoded, QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    QStringList rosTables;
    QString newString;

    while (!stream.atEnd()) {
        int row, col;
        QMap<int, QVariant> roleDataMap;
        stream >> row >> col >> roleDataMap;
        rosTables << roleDataMap[Qt::DisplayRole].toString();
    }

    for (const QString &tableType : rosTables) {
        if (tableType == "Images") {
            QPoint initPos(0, 0);
            auto *wgt = new CustomTableWidget;
            auto *proxyControl = addRect(0, 0, 0, 0, QPen(Qt::black),
                                         QBrush(Qt::darkGreen));
            auto *sizeGrip = new QSizeGrip(wgt);
            auto *layout = new QHBoxLayout(wgt);

            layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            layout->addWidget(sizeGrip, 0, Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignBottom);

            connect(wgt, &CustomTableWidget::sizeChanged, [wgt, proxyControl](){
                proxyControl->setRect(wgt->geometry().adjusted(-10, -10, 10, 10));
            });

            wgt->setColumnCount(2);
            wgt->setRowCount(2);

            for (int ridx = 0; ridx < wgt->rowCount(); ridx++) {
                for (int cidx = 0; cidx < wgt->columnCount(); cidx++) {
                    auto *item = new QTableWidgetItem();

                    item->setText(QString("%1").arg(ridx));
                    wgt->setItem(ridx,cidx,item);
                }
            }

            auto *const proxy = addWidget(wgt);


            proxy->setPos(initPos.x(), initPos.y()
                          + proxyControl->rect().height());
            proxy->setParentItem(proxyControl);

            proxyControl->setPos(initPos.x(), initPos.y());
            proxyControl->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
            proxyControl->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);
            proxyControl->setRect(wgt->geometry().adjusted(-10, -10, 10, 10));
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Use [`QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent::scenePos()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscenedragdropevent.html#scenePos) to properly position the dropped item.

### Result

The proposed change gives you the desired result right away:

[image: Properly positioned handle]

Comment: :) I have bee trying to figure it out all afternoon!! That makes total sense!!!! :) Thanks for your time and I will surely remember it for the next time! Now I can go to sleep :D

Comment: And yes that was a small fix I was trying to make thanks for bring it that up. About `QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent::scenePos()` as soon as I drop it it goes right away in the center but actually it should stay where I drop it (where the mouse is). What am I missing there?

Comment: @Emanuele, You are very welcome! As for the `scenePos`, do not use `QPoint initPos(0,0);`, but `QPoint initPos(event->scenePos());`. This should do the job, but if it doesn't work, let me know and I will try to help you.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried it and switched with `QPoint initPos(event->scenePos());` but I receive : `no matching constructor for initialization of QPoint`

Comment: @Emanuele, What about `QPoint initPos(event->scenePos().toPoint());`?

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately the widget, when dropped, still does not stays under the mouse. Tomorrow I will write another question for that. If you happen to find out what is happening let me know. Again thank you very much for your help!!! :)

Comment: Hey thanks! :) Ok I am writing a couple of question on the same subject. Here is the [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64415930/how-to-connect-a-qradiobutton-of-a-qtablewidget-cell-with-another-qtablewidget-c) and wanted to ask you if you have time and space could you give me a hand with that?

Comment: @Emanuele, you are welcome! I have a solution for the positioning.

Comment: Really? :) I am still trying to figure out what the problem might be with the positioning. What is the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223251/discussion-between-scopchanov-and-emanuele).