# How to properly drop a widget on a QGraphicsView right under the mouse?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsscene

[Following my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64407217/why-qgraphicsproxywidget-does-not-resize-properly-after-dropping-into-qgraphicsv) I have been trying to solve a positioning problem withing a `QGraphicsView`.

After a widget is dragged from a `QListWidget` and dropped inside a `QGraphicsView`, it jumps everywhere.

[image: re]

**The problem** I have been trying to solve with also the help of another user is the following:
As soon as the widget is dragged inside the `QGraphicsView` and dropped. It just goes in random locations and have to pay attention to retrieve it. This behavior is not user friendly and sometimes it takes a bit to locate the widget.

Below the code:

**scene.h**

```
#ifndef SCENE_H
#define SCENE_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>

class Scene : public QGraphicsScene
{
public:
    Scene(QObject *parent = nullptr);

protected:
  void dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
  void dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
  void dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
};

#endif // SCENE_H
```

**scene.cpp**

```
void Scene::dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
    QByteArray encoded =
            event->mimeData()->data("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist");
    QDataStream stream(&encoded, QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    QStringList rosTables;
    QString newString;

    while (!stream.atEnd()) {
        int row, col;
        QMap<int, QVariant> roleDataMap;
        stream >> row >> col >> roleDataMap;
        rosTables << roleDataMap[Qt::DisplayRole].toString();
    }

    for (const QString &tableType : rosTables) {
        if (tableType == "Images") {
            QPoint initPos(0, 0);
            auto *wgt = new CustomTableWidget;
            auto *proxyControl = addRect(0, 0, 0, 0, QPen(Qt::black),
                                         QBrush(Qt::darkGreen));
            auto *sizeGrip = new QSizeGrip(wgt);
            auto *layout = new QHBoxLayout(wgt);

            layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            layout->addWidget(sizeGrip, 0, Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignBottom);

            connect(wgt, &CustomTableWidget::sizeChanged, [wgt, proxyControl](){
                proxyControl->setRect(wgt->geometry().adjusted(-10, -10, 10, 10));
            });

            wgt->setColumnCount(2);
            wgt->setRowCount(2);

            for (int ridx = 0; ridx < wgt->rowCount(); ridx++) {
                for (int cidx = 0; cidx < wgt->columnCount(); cidx++) {
                    auto *item = new QTableWidgetItem();

                    item->setText(QString("%1").arg(ridx));
                    wgt->setItem(ridx,cidx,item);
                }
            }

            auto *const proxy = addWidget(wgt);


            proxy->setPos(initPos.x(), initPos.y()
                          + proxyControl->rect().height());
            proxy->setParentItem(proxyControl);

            proxyControl->setPos(initPos.x(), initPos.y());
            proxyControl->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
            proxyControl->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);
            proxyControl->setRect(wgt->geometry().adjusted(-10, -10, 10, 10));
        }
    }
}
```

**What it was tried so far to solve the problem:**

Now the `QGraphicsScene` have been subclassed to re-write the mouse events, in particular and in this case attention was given to the `dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)` as that is the responsible function to "see the widget"

Several trials and errors were conducted and in the same function it was tried to add the following part:

```
for (const QString &tableType : rosTables) {
    if (tableType == "Images") {
        QPoint initPos(event->scenePos()); // <-- Tried this but no change 
        auto *wgt = new CustomTableWidget;
        auto *proxyControl = addRect(0, 0, 0, 0, QPen(Qt::black),
                                     QBrush(Qt::darkGreen));
        auto *sizeGrip = new QSizeGrip(wgt);
        auto *layout = new QHBoxLayout(wgt);
}
```

An additional thing tried was to provide the `QPoint` the `event->scenePos().toPoint()` as deemed proper for the goal, but unfortunately that didn't solve the problem either:

```
for (const QString &tableType : rosTables) {
    if (tableType == "Images") {
        QPoint initPos(event->scenePos().toPoint()); // <-- Tried this too but no change
        auto *wgt = new CustomTableWidget;
        auto *proxyControl = addRect(0, 0, 0, 0, QPen(Qt::black),
                                     QBrush(Qt::darkGreen));
        auto *sizeGrip = new QSizeGrip(wgt);
        auto *layout = new QHBoxLayout(wgt);
}
```

If anyone has an idea of what the problem might be please provide guidance on how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `proxy->setPos(initPos.x(), initPos.y() + proxyControl->rect().height());` to `proxy->setPos(10, 10);`.
2. Set scene rect:

   ```
    Scene::Scene(QObject *parent) :
        QGraphicsScene(parent)
    {
        setBackgroundBrush(Qt::lightGray);
        setSceneRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
    }
   ```
3. Set view alignment, e.g. in *MainWindow.cpp*:

   ```
    ui->graphicsView->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
   ```